# POI - unable to create custom validation for a range of cells

Tags: constraints, apache-poi, validation

I need to check if the user has entered a valid number in a cells A1:A10. In Excel i would choose the cells and then create a custom validator and set the formula to =isNumber("$A$1:$A10")
Trying do this using POI is getting me all tied in knots:
Here is what i have tried:

```
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 10, 0, 0);
        XSSFDataValidationHelper dvHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);
        DataValidationConstraint customConstraint = dvHelper.createCustomConstraint("isNumber(\"$A$0:$A$10\"");
        XSSFDataValidation validation = (XSSFDataValidation)dvHelper.createValidation(customConstraint, addressList);
        validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
        sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

When i try and open this in Excel, i get an error and Excel disables the validation

thanks in advance
-anish

Comment: You found anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
CellReference crStartCell = new CellReference(startRow, column, true, true); // 0-based row and column index
CellReference crEndCell = new CellReference(endRow, column, true, true);
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dvHelper.createCustomConstraint("ISNUMBER("+crStartCell.formatAsString()+":"+crEndCell.formatAsString() +")");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert that excel to csv than perform your validations using SuperCSV. It would be length but more easier.